# The compounds barium sulfate and potassium chloride are the products of a chemical equation. Write a balanced chemical equation for this reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I have been teaching my cousin grade 10 science.

Unfortunately, I have never taken chemistry before and am unsure how to do these type of questions.

How does one go about approaching this question?

Comment: I would prompt him for everything he knows, get him to write down the part of the equation given in the question.  Take a look at this video https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/chemical-reactions-stoichiome/balancing-chemical-equations/v/balancing-chemical-equations-introduction and take a look here http://www.kentchemistry.com/Worksheets/Regents/Units/MathofChem/WSBalancing21.pdf for some examples, then just do some more internet searching for "balancing chemical equations".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem I am having is not balancing the equations but writing them down as an equation, mainly, getting the subscripts correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since they're ionic compounds you basically just interchange the atoms, while keeping in mind the charges.

Since you know the products are $$\ce{BaSO_4}$$ and $$\ce{KCl}$$
you need to figure out the original composition. If you look at the periodic table and also learning your common ions, you know Barium is 2+ and sulfide is 2-. But the problem is when you interchange them, you have a 2- charge from sulfate with potassium which is 1+, so you must have 2 potassium. Same thing with chloride. Now that you have $$\ce{BaCl_2}$$ and $$\ce{K_2SO_4}$$
you need to balance the equation by putting a 2 in front of potassium chloride.
$$\ce{BaCl_2 + K_2SO_4 <=> BaSO_4 + 2KCl}$$

To sum it up just recognize they are ionic compounds and that you need to balance the equation and charges.

Comment: You did not use the compounds given in the question.  You used sulfite rather than sulfate.  The concept is right, the answer is wrong.

Comment: Yep, fixed that, my bad.

Comment: Yea, such a simple question and we each made a mistake (see comments under my answer).  BTW, you still have barium sulfite in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to look at the links in the comments and search yourself to find the systematic methods for balancing equations. But, just to walk you through this one as an example:

Start him off with

$$\_\_\_\_ + \_\_\_\_\ce{-> BaSO4 + KCl}$$

as the problem states, and ask him to fill in the blanks.  The key is having the same number of each *element* on each side of the equation.  To start off with, for this problem, the left side should have one $\ce{Ba}$, one $\ce{S}$, four $\ce{O}$'s, one $\ce{K}$ and one $\ce{Cl}$ just like the right side.  You will need to do some searching to learn about changing the amounts of each *element* in the equation so that you end up with the same number of each *element*.  That cannot be properly explained in this space, but I will work out this specific very simple (grade 10 level) problem.

This problem is simple because you can just switch around the ions (look up ions if needed) so you start with $\ce{K2SO4}$ and $\ce{BaCl2}$.  The only complication here is that the starting material has twice as many $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions, so to make things balance you need to have two on the right side. So  he needs to take that information to get: 
$$\ce{K2SO4 + BaCl2-> BaSO4 + 2KCl}$$

Again, the problem with my description is that it is just to kind of give you the basic idea by walking through a single example.  There are well defined methods for doing this and that is what your student needs to learn.  There are many good YouTube videos that would be worth watching.  I would follow the links in my comment, find some more sites on your own then try this problem now that you have the answer and some guidance from a different point of view (mine).

Comment: Well the reaction is really $$\ce{K2SO4 + BaCl2-> BaSO4 v + 2KCl}$$ The reactants and the KCl product are really the solvated ions not the salts.

Comment: @MaxW, absolutely.  Given the context of this question I thought achieving mass balance was the key point to make without explaining phase changes.  Maybe it would have been simple enough to define the appropriate terms though.

Comment: LOL - Obvious to us, but not to the OP Ali...